# oracle 12c using subquery factoring clause with plsql declaration

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, subquery-factoring

I'm a big fan of the subquery factoring clause.

```
WITH t1 as (select 1 as id from dual)
select * from t1;
```

and oracle 12c now  includes a PL/SQL declaration section in the WITH clause

```
WITH
  FUNCTION with_function(p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN p_id;
  END;
SELECT with_function(id)
FROM   t1
WHERE  rownum = 1
```

but I can't seem to get them to work together is it possible?

```
WITH t1 as (select 1 as id from dual)
WITH  FUNCTION with_function(p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN p_id;
  END;
SELECT with_function(id)
FROM   t1
WHERE  rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the syntax:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702

[image]

plsql_declarations
[image]

subquery_factoring_clause
[image]

As you see, the syntax is:

```
WITH [ plsql_declarations ] [ subquery_factoring_clause ]
```

This means that PL/SQL must go first, then a rest of SQL query, in this way:

```
WITH 
  FUNCTION with_function(p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN p_id;
  END;
t1 as (select 1 as id from dual)
SELECT with_function(id)
FROM   t1
WHERE  rownum = 1;
```